# json serialize list in list

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization

I get a list with list in json And want to convert the json to matrixList Object but cant get it to work Im getting this error

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

here is my code

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
matrixList mxList = (matrixList)json_serializer.DeserializeObject("{ \"matrix\": "[[\"1\",\"email1@gmail.com\"],[\"2\",\"email2@gmail.com\"],[\"3\",\"email3@gmail.com\"],[\"4\",\"email4@gmail.com\"]]" }");
```

The values of the Json is just an example

```
public class matrixList
{
    public List<List<string>> matrix { get; set; }
}
```

My question then why wont it work I have searched on the error and only found some with Json syntax error but Im not able to see any error.

Tahks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a RootObject first.

```
public class RootObject
{
public RootObject(){}
public List<string> itemList{get;set;}
}
```

Then try deserializing to the RootObject type.
When deserializing Lists this works with Newtonsoft.JSON serializer.

`serializer.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonInput);`

Comment: Used newtonsoft like this 
 matrixList mxList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<matrixList>(" Json ");

And it worked thanks ! :D