# Newton Json Deserialize Array of array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Hi I am having trouble deserializing some JSON into a c#.net class using newtonsoft desrializeobject

Example JSON

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "Colour": "Red"
        },
        {
            "cid": "1",
            "Shape": "Square"
        },
        {
            "cid": "2",
            "Shape": "Circle"
        }
    ]
]
```

I want this to appear in my C#.net class like this excuse the typos and syntax but you get the general idea.

```
public class object {

 public int id;
 public string colour;
 public Shape[] shapes;

}

public class Shape {
  public int cid;
  public string shapename;
}
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: JSON array you have posted in question is not valid, because it has 3 elements one contains id and anohter two contains cid, they are not nested array elements, please varify.

Comment: @Mak The JSON is valid (try it at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)), although it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @GrayFoxNZ The JSON does not seem to match the class structure you have laid out.  Is this your actual JSON?

Comment: Its not my JSON.  The classes I made are just what I was thinking they would look like without knowing to much about JSON formatting and deserialisation.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer over here:

[json serialize list in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288830/json-serialize-list-in-list/23289038#23289038)

You should create a RootObject first. Which represents the first List.
The RootObject contains a List with your Shape class

You could also specify the [JsonProperty] annotations to make sure the correct Json properties are mapped to your Shape object.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, that's not what the class is serializing into. If you paste that JSON as a class in Visual Studio, and you get this:

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[][] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }
        public string cid { get; set; }
        public string Shape { get; set; }
    }
```

So the issue is the JSON. If that's not your JSON and you can't do anything to fix the formatting of it, I'd serialize it into a dynamic object first and then do the necessary transformations.

Comment: Yea its not my JSON ill try your suggestion tonight.  thanks mate